# making .exe from .bat file tools and solution with dependencies

Tags: batch-file, exe, pentaho

I have got a solution that uses a .bat file to start. I need to make it a .exe. I have used different tools like [BATch to EXE], [Bat_to_exe_converter], [Bat to Exe Converter](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html)  from [f2ko] which was the most modern one. I need help on the last one which is more sensible to work. or any other solution that makes a working .exe file. Right now, after converting the file to exe according to dependencies the start-up process will not complete. I should mention that the bat file is the Pentaho start-up file.
I have also used IEXPRESS from windows but the error after running the result exe is:
"Error creating process . Reason: The system cannot find the file specified."

Thanks,

Comment: You need to post the code of the batch file otherwise, we're flying blind.

Comment: it's too long, but part of it: @echo off
setlocal
cd /D %~dp0
cscript promptuser.js //nologo //e:jscript
rem errorlevel 0 means user chose "no"
if %errorlevel%==0 goto quit
echo WScript.Quit(1); > promptuser.js

call set-pentaho-env.bat "%~dp0jre"

cd tomcat\bin
set CATALINA_HOME=%~dp0tomcat
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
rem Make sure we set the appropriate variable so Tomcat can start (e.g. JAVA_HOME iff. _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME points to a JDK)

Comment: if not exist "%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%\bin\jdb.exe" goto noJdk
if not exist "%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJdk
set JAVA_HOME=%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%
set JRE_HOME=
set -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
goto start

:noJdk

Comment: rem If no JDK found at %_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME% unset JAVA_HOME and set JRE_HOME so Tomcat doesn't misinterpret JAVA_HOME == JDK_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=
set JRE_HOME=%_PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME%

:start
call startup
:quit
endlocal

Comment: @MattWilliamson I don't know how to add the file.

Comment: Why do you need it to be an EXE? Pentaho is a large Java application with many dependencies. I can't think of any advantage having spoon.bat or kitchen.bat converted to an EXE would bring.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers the main need is to make pentaho work as a service on the server. and starts automatically with server start up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need Carte. Carte is a web service that allows remote execution of jobs and transforms.

[Carte User Doumentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation)

You'll probably also need to see this:

[Carte as a Windows Service](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+as+a+Windows+Service)